Problemas para cargar archivo FXML en JavaFX con Maven: getResource devuelve null
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación JavaFX en IntelliJ IDEA utilizando Maven, y tengo problemas para cargar un archivo FXML desde el código. Al intentar cargar el archivo pago-view.fxml con FXMLLoader, obtengo null en la ruta de getResource, lo que impide que el archivo se cargue correctamente.

El archivo pago-view.fxml está ubicado en
src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/.

El método en el    controlador que intenta cargar pago-view.fxml es
el siguiente:
 public class CompraController {
 @FXML
 protected void pagar() throws Exception {
     System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));
     AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));
 }}



Cuando ejecuto System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));, el resultado es null, lo que indica que la ruta no se encuentra en el classpath.
Estructura del proyecto:
src/main/java: contiene las clases Java, incluyendo CompraController.
src/main/resources: contiene los archivos FXML, con la estructura src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml.
Mi archivo pom.xml incluye el plugin de Maven para JavaFX:
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>co.edu.javeriana.proyectobdd.HelloApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

También he intentado agregar la configuración en  para asegurar que los archivos FXML se copien correctamente:
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

Después de ejecutar mvn clean package, el archivo FXML aparece en target/classes/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, pero FXMLLoader aún no puede encontrarlo.

Verifiqué que src/main/resources esté configurado como carpeta de
recursos en IntelliJ.
He ejecutado mvn javafx:run para asegurar que el classpath esté
correctamente configurado.
Probé con diferentes rutas en getResource, como
"/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml" y
"co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml".

¿Cómo puedo asegurarme de que el archivo FXML esté en el classpath y que FXMLLoader pueda encontrarlo correctamente? ¿Hay alguna configuración adicional en Maven o IntelliJ que deba considerar?

No uso JavaFx, pero siendo "hermano" de Java, creo que puedes probar las siguiemtes rutas: /src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, o src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, o /main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml o main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, o /resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, o resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, alguna de estas debería funcionar.

En el pom.xml debes agregar estas dependencias
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-media -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

No hay la necesidad de colocar un plugin pero si debes configurar variables para la Virtual Machine de Java para pueda ejecutar las librerias de javafx ya que estas no vienen en el mismo JDK.
--module-path
"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.12\lib"
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web

Para cargar un recurso local puedes hacerlo de esta manera
public Resource recurso(String carpetas){
    Resource resource = 
                new ClassPathResource(carpetas);
    return resource;
}

Para cargar el FXML y ejecutarlo, lo realizo en 2 partes por comodidad
public Parent cargadorFXML(String nombreVentana) {
    Parent root = null;
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);

    try {
        URL direccionFisica = this.recurso("/vistas/"+nombreVentana).getURL();

        fxmlLoader.setLocation(direccionFisica);
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(VentanasServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return root;
}


public void desplegarNuevaVentana(String nombreVentana) {       
    final Stage ventana = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        ventana.setTitle("Prototipo");

        // stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("recursos/carpeta.png").toExternalForm()));
        Parent root = this.cargadorFXML(nombreVentana);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(null);
        ventana.setScene(scene);

        ventana.setResizable(false);
        ventana.sizeToScene();

        this.movimientosVentana(scene, ventana);
        efectosEspecialesService.desvanecencia(root, TIEMPO_ESPERA);

        ventana.show();
}

